# PrimeFaces Datatable Right Click Select + Row Specific Context Menu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

I have a simple datatable with 3 columns, that displays AccessCard Entities In one column I have a "Status" which may be lets say "INACTIVE", "DELETED" etc. Obviously these values are derived from the backing bean.

So if lets say `#{card.accessCard.flgDeleted} == true` then "INACTIVE" is displayed

In the context menu I have an option "Flag as Deleted" which sets `flgDeleted == false`.
I dont want the delete option to be rendered if `flgDeleted == false`.

With the code I have implemented till now, when I select the row with LEFT click everything works ok. When I use RIGHT click to select a row and show the context menu at the same time the backing bean does not seem to be updated.
Interestingly enough, if RIGHT click on a row and actually choose lets say Flag as Deleted it does everything fine.

```
<p:contextMenu id="contextMenu" for="cardTable">

            <p:menuitem value="View Card History" icon="ui-icon-search"/>


            <p:menuitem value="Flag as Deleted" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                process="@form" update="@form" oncomplete="dlgDeleteCard.show()"
                rendered="#{!card.accessCard.flgDeleted}" />
</p:contextMenu>



<h:panelGrid style="width:500px;">

            <p:dataTable var="pc" id="cardTable" widgetVar="cardTable"
                value="#{card.accessCardList}" 
                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{card.accessCard}" 
                 rowKey="#{pc.cardId}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{card.onRowSelect}"
                    update="@form :messages" />

                <p:column id="cardId" width="20%" headerText="Card Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{pc.cardId}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="cardHolderName" width="50%"
                    headerText="Current Holder">
                    <h:outputText value="#{pc.currentHolder}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="cardStatus" width="10%" headerText="Status">
                     #{card.getCardStatus(pc)}
                </p:column>


            </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 8):

If anyone still needs it, use:

```
<p:ajax event="contextMenu" update=":MyComponent"/>
```

Comment: Which component is MyComponent?

Comment: in case of 1st post i supose <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update=":cardTable"/>

Comment: I guess, it's about PrimeFace 3.5 (taking release dates and question date into account). Newer Versions should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solve by moving contextMenu in the panelGrid, right after dataTable, then I did not need any javascript hack.